# Excel - pick specific characters from a string after a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of strings where I want to split the numbers and alphabets part. For e.g. in cell A1 I have "FNN-12345 - Sample Text - 2016_AA1.1" (without the quotes ""). I want to split it to get just "Sample Text - 2016_AA1.1".

Appreciate any guidance on the formula.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the universal solution, no matter what the first alphanumeric string is:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" - ",A1)-2)
```

It finds the first occurence of the string " - " and keeps only the part after that string.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions to manipulate strings of characters in Excel like [Left](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c), [Right](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f) or [Mid](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MID-MIDB-functions-D5F9E25C-D7D6-472E-B568-4ECB12433028) to get the desired result in combination with a [Lenghth](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/LEN-LENB-functions-29236F94-CEDC-429D-AFFD-B5E33D2C67CB) function.

As such for you result you could try :

`=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - LEN("FNN-12345 - "))`

This formula would take the length of the entire cell and remove the `FNN-12345 -` part. Of course you can add a column which contain the desired elements to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If the text which you want to select begin always on the position 13 (as in your example), use the formula

```
    =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A2)-12)
```

(supposing your original text is in the cell A1).

If you recognize the start of text by the pattern `" - "`, use the formula

```
    =RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3) -FIND(" - ",A4)-LEN(" - ")+ 1)
```